# How can a permission a directory so that a user can list the contents, but cannot read them

Tags: permissions, vsftpd

I am setting up a vstpd FTP server where people can upload files to be processed. I want them to be able to write and see the list of files, but not actually download them. I'm using virtual users which handles this via linux permissioning.

Comment: Your last sentence isn't clear. Do you mean that each person who uses your service has their own unix account on the Linux server (i.e. they get entries in `/etc/passwd`)?

Comment: As an alternative to changing file permissions, you can change the `cmds_allowed` setting to prohibit use of the `RETR` command.

Comment: True, was able to do this adding: ```download_enable=NO```, but curious about the permissioning method.

Answer (score 1):

Change the directory to allow listing file entries and write to it:

```
chmod +rwx .
```

Do not allow reading the files themselves:

```
chmod -r *
```

This works only for existing files. For new files use `umask` before starting your server:

```
umask -- -r
```

Read the man page of the command for more details.

Comment: Note that this assumes that the FTP user doesn't own the file: if the FTP user owns the file then they can `chmod` them.